# Ember handlebars doesn't recognize a RecordArray that was passed

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm fighting with a reading-list Ember app. Basically, I'm looping on the books handlebar over a RecordArray called model, that according to Ember doesn't exist.

This is the code:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('books');
  this.route('show', {path: '/books/:book_id'});
  this.route('reviews', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
  this.route('genre', {path: '/genres/:genre_id'});
});
```

**books.hbs**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled books">
    {{#each books as |book|}}
      {{book-details book=book}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**book.js router**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      books: this.store.find('book'),
      authors: this.store.find('author'),
      genres: this.store.find('genre')
    })
  }
});
```

**books.js controller**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  // model is what is returned from the model hook
  books: function() {
    return this.get('model.model');
  }.property('model.model'),
  genres: function() {
    return this.get('model.genres');
  }.property('model.genres'),
  authors: function() {
    return this.get('model.authors');
  }.property('model.authors')
});
```

When visiting `/books` everything works as expected. However when visiting `/`, it doesn't work. Ember inspector shows the presence of a RecordArray called books, but it's not rendering it.

**index.hbs (/)**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    {{render 'books' books}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    {{render 'authors' authors}}
    {{render 'genres' genres}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**index.js router**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      books: this.store.find('book'),
      genres: this.store.find('genre'),
      authors: this.store.find('author')
    })
  }
});
```

**index.js controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  books: function() {
    return this.get('model.books');
  }.property('model.books'),
  genres: function() {
    return this.get('model.genres');
  }.property('model.genres'),
  authors: function() {
    return this.get('model.authors');
  }.property('model.authors')
});
```

[Code in Github](https://github.com/FranGoitia/todo)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't for the fact that the `model` property is being overwritten, your `model` computed property would be an infinite loop, it references itself.

### Controller

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  // model is what is returned from the model hook
  books: Ember.computed.alias('model.model'),
  genres: Ember.computed.alias('model.genres'),
  authors: Ember.computed.alias('model.authors')
});
```

### Template

```
<ul class="list-unstyled books">
    {{#each books as |book|}}
      {{book-details book=book}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

#### Update to modified code:

When you call render you are passing in `books` as the model.  It's grabbing the `books` controller and `books` template, then your `books` property in the controller is trying to grab the property `books` off of the model, which is already the collection of books.  Just do `{{render books model}}` from your template, or better, create a component that shares the books code and then you can do something like this `{{book-list books=model}}` etc.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial code. The thing is that now the home page where I call render to display books, authors and genres, doesn't show the books. I just edited the question and added more info. Thanks !

Comment: Try using `model.model.[]`, `model.genres.[]` and `model.authors.[]` inside the call to `.property(...)` - This creates a computed property that updates when items are added/removed from the dependant array.. I don't know why that would fix it since you're using `RSVP.hash` - but it doesn't hurt to try..

Comment: Replacing books for model didn't work. I updated the post putting the github repo with the code in case it helps. I'm going to try to implement the books-list component approach, but I'm really curious and would like to understand why this other approach is not working.

Comment: Creating a component called and calling it works. {{books-list books=books}} works. But {{render 'books' books}}, doesn't. Do you know what's the reason ?